# Show all users and their groups/vice versa

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, users, groups

I know I have existing groups and users but I'm not sure about their association. Is there an shell command I can use to list all users or all groups and a command to list all groups/users for a specified user/group?

So something like `showusers` would list all users, and `showgroups -u thisuser` would show all the groups that have `thisuser` in it.

Comment: there is no such command. You need to script it by your self.

Comment: how about `cat /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 127, accepted):

All users:

```
$ getent passwd
```

All groups:

```
$ getent group
```

All groups with a specific user:

```
$ getent group | grep username
```

Comment: I found that there is a user named `speech-dispatcher` that belongs to group audio (based on `groups speech-dispatcher`). But it is not listed under `getent group` command! What is the problem?

Comment: @PHPLearner If you have another question, please [post a question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask), not a comment.

Comment: +1 since this will also list users/groups not found in the conventional `/etc/passwd` & `/etc/group` files i.e. when a system is configured to use central directories such NIS and LDAP, or any other alternative user/group database, as long as that supports user/group enumeration.

Comment: This will not return all users and groups in an ldap or sssd config if enumeration is turned off.

Answer (score 25):

List users and their groups:

```
for user in $(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd); do groups $user; done
```

List groups and their users:

```
cat /etc/group | awk -F: '{print $1, $3, $4}' | while read group gid members; do
    members=$members,$(awk -F: "\$4 == $gid {print \",\" \$1}" /etc/passwd);
    echo "$group: $members" | sed 's/,,*/ /g';
done
```

Comment: While that would probably work, it seems a bit overly complicated, doesn't it, when there are perfectly good simple one-shot commands to do this?

Comment: It certainly wouldn't get anything that lives in a centralized repository. And that's definitely information that you'd want to see.

Comment: Excellent very helpful, it would be better to mention that they are seperate commands.

Answer (score 8):

If you dont care about remote users such as LDAP or NIS,
to list users and their associated groups in a simple way:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs groups
```

Output;

> ```
> root : root
> myuser : root www-data fuse 
> anotheruser : anotheruser   cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev scanner bluetooth netdev
> ```

Comment: This has the same problem as Chang's answer in that it ignores users/groups originating in databases such as LDAP, NIS, etc.

Comment: This very neatly outputs the information in an incredibly clear format though, so can still be a useful first step. It helped jog my memory regarding the syntax of /etc/group and /etc/passwd!

Answer (score 3):

## List all users

```
cut -d':' -f 1 /etc/passwd
```

Or

```
awk -F ':' '{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

While *cat /etc/passwd* shows all users (and a bunch of other stuff), *cut -d ':' -f 1* is a simple way to split each line with ':' as a delimiter and extract just the first field (users). Pretty much the same as awk version.

## List all groups

```
cut -d':' -f 1 /etc/group
```

Or

```
awk -F ':' '{print $1}' /etc/group
```

Guess what, very simmilar to listing users. Just parse */etc/group* instead.

Another interesting way, maybe closer to what OP wanted, is *compgen*. Not sure about compatibility issues though.

```
compgen -u
compgen -g
```

Comment: Hi Elliot Baily, welcome to Server Fault! Please note that this question is over 5 years old, and already has a correct and accepted answer. Also note that your solution only works if users are stored in /etc/passwd; the accepted answer also works for other user databases (such as NIS or LDAP). If you want to answer old questions (which is perfectly fine!) you might want to have a look at [the list of unanswered questions](https://serverfault.com/unanswered) - plenty of questions looking for some love!

Answer (score 0):

Use `getent passwd{1000..60000}` to list only manually added users. See: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-list-users-in-linux/

```
for user in $(getent passwd {1000..60000} |awk -F: '{print $1}');
do 
    groups $user; 
done
```

Answer (score -1):

for debian

```
cat /etc/passwd # show all users
cat /etc/group # show all groups
cat /etc/passwd | grep group # show all users with specified group
```

Comment: In contrast with the already accepted this does not list users/groups that originate from a remote user database such as LDAP, NIS etc....

Answer (score -3):

Like this:

```
sudo cat /etc/gshadow |grep group
sudo cat /etc/gshadow |grep username
```

Comment: No. `/etc/gshadow` doesn't contain group members (`/etc/group` does) and the accepted answer from 4.5 years ago is much more general anyway, as it also handles remote groups.

Answer (score -3):

Use this command to get all the group and users in that particular group.

```
grep '
> ' /etc/group
```